# Getting an error using EXISTS operator but correct result with IN operator in

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, exists

[image]I am getting an error `An expression of non-Boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected` while using `EXISTS` But when I am using `IN` operator it is giving the correct result.

Below is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMh9Z.jpg)both query

```
SELECT * FROM emp
WHERE Emp_id IN (SELECT Emp_id FROM Department WHERE Department.Emp_id=emp.Emp_id)

SELECT * FROM emp Department
WHERE emp.Emp_id EXISTS (SELECT Emp_id FROM Department WHERE emp.Emp_id=Department.Emp_id)
```

Comment: you don't show *why* you are trying to involve Department in your query; can you explain what you are actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXISTS is a unary operator, not a binary operator, and takes only a subquery as its argument.  You say:

```
WHERE EXISTS (subquery...)
```

not

```
WHERE somefield EXISTS (subquery...)
```

Since EXISTS merely tests whether the subquery would return at least one row, the fields selected are not relevant and people commonly do:

```
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ...)
```

though selecting null or any other value or multiple values works just the same.

Answer (score 1):

`EXISTS` operator only checks whether any result is found or not. It cannot bind and compare found results with given column name so that it can not be used with this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

Now, I am aware that EXISTS keyword, unlike IN, does not compare, but it checks whether any result is found.

Now I can get the same result using NESTED SUBQUERY, CORRELATED SUBQUERY, and JOIN of All employees who work in any department using[image] Below is the Query.

```
SELECT * FROM emp
WHERE Emp_id IN (SELECT Emp_id FROM Department)

SELECT * FROM emp
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Emp_id FROM Department WHERE emp.Emp_id=Department.Emp_id)

SELECT e.Emp_id, e.E_Name, e.Salary, e.E_Address FROM emp e RIGHT JOIN Department d ON e.Emp_id=d.Emp_id
```